# Strcpy to copy struct name to char array?

Tags: c

I have a struct which has a name variable, i.e.:

```
l->name
```

I also have an array of characters:

```
char highest1[50];
```

I want to copy `l->name` into `highest1[50]`, but I cannot do that.

Am I doing anything illegal here?

```
strcpy(highest1[50], l->name);

runtime error: index 50 out of bounds for type 'char [50]'
```

I tried increasing `char[50]` to `char [99]` but then I got:

```
runtime error - illegal array, pointer or other operation
```

And something about deadly ASAN Signal?

Comment: Did you try `strcpy(highest1, l->name);`?

Comment: And how's `name` declared?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I doing anything illegal here:

```
strcpy(highest1[50], l->name);
```

Yes code is doing an illegal thing here.

`highest1[50]` is the value of element 50, some integer value,  and that is being treated as an address of where to copy to.

Also with `char highest1[50];`, attempting to find the value outside the array with  `highest1[50]` is *undefined behavior* (UB).

To avoid such basic mistakes

1) Enable all complier warnings to save you time.   2) Copy to `highest1[]` in a way to not overflow its size.

```
size_t len = strlen(l->name);
if (len >= sizeof highest1) Handle_Error();
else {
  strcpy(highest1, l->name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing anything illegal here:

Yes: two things

1. Valid indices for `highest1` are 0 through 49.
2. You want `strcpy(highest1, l->name)` because `highest1[0]` is a character, *not* a pointer to one.

Comment: Detail: Valid indices for `highest1[]` are 0 through 50  if code wants to compute the address.   Valid indices for `highest1[]` are 0 through 49 if code wants to reference the element value.

Answer (score 0):

`highest1[50]` is the 51 element of `highest` so you are passing basically a wrong address to `strcpy` which takes as input two `char` pointers.

You should call `strcpy(highest1, l->name)` because the name of the array is the address location of the first element.

Please note also that if you have a string of 4 chars ex. "aaaa" then the array should be of 5 elements to contain the terminating character '\0'.